# asp.net core EF связь многие ко многим

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Не пойму как работать с данными в БД. На данный момент имеем:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст БД

```
public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
}
```

Как добавлять обновлять данные?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через репозиторий:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    public T Get(Int32? id) => Entities.Find(id);

    public void Create(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Entities == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            Entities.Add(item);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    errorMessage += String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public void Delete(Int32 id)
    {
        T entity = Get(id);
        try
        {
            if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            Entities.Remove(entity);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate) => Entities.Where(predicate).ToList();

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() => Table.AsEnumerable();

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В EF Core 5 упростили создание связи многие-ко-многим. Нет необходимости создавать промежуточную модель, и упростилась работа с добавлением и обновлением данных. Здесь хорошо описано https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php

Answer (score 0):

Расул Абд, интересное описание по ссылке. Хорошо, если бы вы пояснили на этом примере, как связи работают без промежуточной модели:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }= new List<Student>();
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
 
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=relationsdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

Comment: Не стоит оставлять комментарии в поле для ответов. Это сообщение пожалуйста удалите.